# Calling A Child Component Inside a Map Function In ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, map-function

i have an state of array time and have data in it.what i want to do is map through this state and call a child components with props

My State

```
 this.state = { 
  user:'',
 feedArray:[],

 }
```

Function To Set Data

```
  //I CALLED THIS IN COMPONENTDIDMOUNT
  renderFeed(){
  rdb.ref("feeds").once('value',(snapshot)=>{
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{
    this.setState({feedArray:Object.values(childSnapshot.val())})

})
 }).then(()=>{
console.log(this.state.feedArray);
})
```

}

return part

```
 render() { 

    if (this.state.feedArray) {
      this.state.feedArray.map((feed,id)=>{
        console.log(feed.body);   //this works fine
        return (<FeedElement id={feed.id} body={feed.body}/> );  //This Not Works

      })

    }
     }
```

This Is The log Cosoled on console.log(this.state.feedArray)

```
(4) […]
​
0: Object { author: "AashiqOtp", body: "kkk", feedid: "-M1_6POMRyqRv2tIKrF9", … }
​
1: Object { author: "AashiqOtp", body: "kkk", feedid: "-M1_6XYaUAlsXlwnAbcp", … }
​
2: Object { author: "AashiqOtp", body: "f", feedid: "-M1_HB07eh_08OFFRBbO", … }
​
3: Object { author: "AashiqOtp", body: "we have a new rm", feedid: "-M1d4xwLmSUKA0RZlH-Q", … }
```

Any Ideas? Thanks In Advance

Comment: No need for `if`, add `return` before your `map`.

Comment: shows error :  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions   on wrapping map function inside return()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

can you pass feed.feedid instead of feed.id and return before the the map function.

```
render() { 

if (this.state.feedArray) {
  return this.state.feedArray.map((feed,id)=>
    (<FeedElement id={feed.id} body={feed.body}/> );  //This Not Works
   )

}else {
    return null;
}
 }
```

Hopefully it should work

Comment: No need for the `else` in this, but it doesn't hurt to have it there if you like it.

Comment: else is needed because if this.state.feedArray is false or null or undefined then it will throw error because render needs to return but without else it won't return anything and it will give error

Answer (score 1):

```
this.state.feedArray.map((feed,id)=>{
        console.log(feed.body); 
        return (<FeedElement id={id} body={feed.body}/> );  Works
      })
```

**feed.id** is equivalent to `feed[id]` and if **id** is not present inside the array of objects then accessing it throws **undefined**, however from the console.log you provided the `feed` has `feed.feedid`, you can either pass `id={feed.feedid}` or `id={id}`